# VS2012: проблема с подсветкой синтаксиса

Tags: настройка, цвета, visual-studio, синтаксис

Иногда, когда в коде появляется незакрытая скобка  или некоторые другие ошибки, возникает следующая проблема (картинка ниже):

[image]

Как вы можете видеть, пропадает подсветка некоторых участков кода, причем пропадает как правило во всём файле. С некоторой вероятностью это решается запуском отладчика или же просто сохранением файла (ctrl+s), но если не получается приходится перезапускать VS. Странно именно то, что типы переменных, инклюды и некоторый другой код продолжает подсвечиваеться. 
Как сделать так, чтобы код всегда подсвечивался, как в нижней части картинки?

Поставил себе плагин VAssistX, поковырялся в настройках, проблему решить не удалось. Хотя подсветка VS меня полностью устраевает, но, может, можно как-то переложить эту функцию на это расширение?